# What are the asked coordinates in a kown right triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, angle

I've the following problem:

[image]

Find the coordinates $(n,m)$ and I know the values of $a,b,c$ (b is straight) and $(x,y)$. I also know that $n>x$ and $m>y$. How can I write $(n,m)$ in terms of the things I know?

I've no idea where to start

Comment: Is the $b$ side horizontal? If not, there are an infinite number of solutions. Even in that case, there are two solutions with $(n,m)$ above or below the $b$ side.

Comment: @Andrei according to the edit, yes it is straight.

Comment: @DavidK No, they are coordinates.

Comment: Presumably, all sides of the triangle are _straight._ The alternative is that they are _curved,_ which would make things even less well determined. If side $b$ is _horizontal_ and the coordinates are also in the conventional orientation, then the coordinates of the unlabeled vertex are $(x+b,y).$ Are they?

Comment: @DavidK yes that is indeed correct

Comment: Please add the questions asked in comments to the question

Answer (score 2):

If the side $b$ is horizontal, then draw the perpendicular from $(n,m)$ to the $b$ side. The coordinates of the intersection are $(n,y)$. Then we can write $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ in the original right angle triangle and in the new right angle triangle as $$\sin\alpha=\frac cb=\frac{|m-y|}a\\\cos\alpha=\frac ab=\frac{|n-x|}a$$ 
By solving these equations you get 
$$m=y\pm\frac{ac}b\\n=x\pm\frac{a^2}b$$

Comment: Because $n>x$  and $m>y$ should I take the plus sign?

Comment: Yes. The lengths $a,$, $b$, $c$ are all positive

Comment: @Jan. The value of $y$ is given in the problem (the $(x,y)$ point is known).